# Why building a custom nginx/ModSecurity RPM will result into broken Perl dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, centos7, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to provide an custom nginx/ModSecurity/3rd-party-module RPM, which can be installed on internal servers (no internet) via own RPM repository.

To achieve this, I created an RPM spec file (following are snippets out of the original spec):

```
Name:           nginx
Version:        1.14.0
Release:        1
Group:          System Environment/Daemons
License:        BSD
URL:            http://nginx.net/
Source0:        http://nginx.org/download/nginx-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRequires:  pcre-devel
BuildRequires:  openssl-devel
BuildRequires:  zlib-devel
BuildRequires:  libxslt-devel
BuildRequires:  gd-devel
BuildRequires:  GeoIP-devel
BuildRequires:  pam-devel
BuildRequires:  libmodsecurity-devel
Requires:       pcre
Requires:       openssl
Requires:       zlib
Requires:       libxslt
Requires:       gd
Requires:       GeoIP
Requires:       pam
Requires:       libmodsecurity
```

The full RPM spec with additional rpmbuild files are available here: https://gist.github.com/soerenkornetzki/3731113644ab1084ed9549795b5987d6

The issue is, that when I try to install the RPM, I will face broken dependency errors:

```
Error: Package: nginx-1.14.0-1.x86_64 (/nginx-1.14.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: perl(Data::Types)
Error: Package: nginx-1.14.0-1.x86_64 (/nginx-1.14.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: /opt/local/bin/perl
Error: Package: nginx-1.14.0-1.x86_64 (/nginx-1.14.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: perl(Acme::Comment)
Error: Package: nginx-1.14.0-1.x86_64 (/nginx-1.14.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: perl(Data::Validate::URI)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I am aware, that nginx has a Perl module, but I do not include it within the compile arguments (see full spec with Gist).

I do not have required (any) the Perl modules with `BuildRequires` or `Requires`.

My expectation is that none of the 3rd party modules are using Perl either. This might be a false assumption but I have not checked this since the *required* modules are not installed on the build system and the binary works on it (no RPM install involved, just executed the nginx binary).

The RPM is for CentOS 7 which does not come with `perl-Data-Types` (to name one example). There *was* `perl-Data-Types` with old CentOS 6 (EPEL) but it is not available anymore with CentOS 7 and above (as shown with [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=perl-Data-Types&submit=Search+...)).

As the nginx binary works just fine and only the RPM installer is rejecting the installation:

How to fix this? Where do the requires packages came from?

Answer (score 1):

rpmbuild looks into files in %files and if any contains `use Data::Types` then rpmbuild will automatically add `Requires: perl(Data::Types)`

Extract your rpm file:

```
rpmdev-extract nginx.rpm
```

And look for that module load:

```
grep -r 'Data::Types' .
```

I guess there will be some file, with that line.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, `rpmbuild` is looking at shebangs (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/perl`), and if it finds what looks to be a Perl script, *and* if your build system comes with `perl-generators`, then it will automatically generate `Requires` and `Provides` for Perl files installed by your package.

E.g. if your package is installing a Perl file with a statements like `use Data::Validate::URI`, you end up with `Requires: perl(Data::Validate::URI)` in your RPM file.

It's easy to package missing Perl modules, with `cpanspec` utility.

Aside from this your `Requires: libmodsecurity` is incorrect - you have to let RPM find the proper library dependency instead of "hardcording" it.

For an up-to-date ModSecurity nginx module, as well as library dependency and Perl modules, refer to [this repository](https://extras.getpagespeed.com/redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/nginx-module-security.html) (as in: no need to package anything, was already done).